# Problem with setting up mySql on Fedora 36

Tags: mysql, fedora, dnf, community-server

I'm trying to install mySql on Fedora 36. Firstly I have written some commands as tutorials suggest (https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-8-on-fedora/):

```
sudo dnf update
```

and configured file /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo:

```
[mysql80-community]
name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

As I try to follow the next step:

```
sudo dnf install mysql-community-server
```

I get the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH08e.png)

Comment: Please do not use images for frivolous reasons.  Just copy/paste or type in error here.

Answer (score 0):

From https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/, there is no 36 directory for fc36.

Comment: I noticed it, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: By biased MariaDB employer affiliation would say use MariaDB with our new [mirrorbits](https://mariadb.org/mirrorbits/) service, and a `baseurl` of `https://rpm.mariadb.org/10.8/fedora36-amd64` :-)